# socket_listen(): unable to listen on socket [22]

Tags: php, sockets

I have lots of questions about PHP sockets.

I successfully done the `socket_write()` part, but not `socket_listen()`

As my `socket_bind()` didn't open any port (I am not sure if bind should open port or just bind ip's, but when I write my phone IP it told can't assign requested IP, and when I tried socket_connect it returned error[111], and when I checked with netstat and telnet the port wasn't open) I decided to open port with nc

```
nc -kl 47832
```

Then I wrote this in my test.php file
so the code checks if I am with my PC(localhost) it should connect to 127.0.0.1

and if I am with phone (not localhost) it connects to 192.168.43.124 (My PCs IP)

```
$forloop;
if ($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]=="localhost") {
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Err: " . socket_last_error());
    socket_connect($socket, "127.0.0.1", 47832) or die("Err: " . socket_last_error());
    $result = socket_listen($socket) or die("can't set up listener");
    $spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("err: can't accept");
    $input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
    $resinput = trim($input);
    //echo socket_get_option();
    
    socket_close($spawn);
    socket_close($socket);
}
else {
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Err: " . socket_last_error());
    socket_connect($socket, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 47832);
    socket_write($socket, "needreload", 10)  or die("Could not write output\n");
    sleep(1);
    socket_close($socket);
}
    
function whilefunc() {
    $GLOBALS['forloop'] = 1;
    if (!isset($GLOBALS['forloop'])) {
        while ($GLOBALS['forloop'] == 1) {
            if ($GLOBALS['input']=="needreload") {
                //loadchat();
                socket_successful();
            }
        }
    }
}
    
function socket_successful() {
    $GLOBALS['forloop']=0;
    echo "<h2>msg recieved:" . $GLOBALS['input'] . "</h2>";
    $resinput="";
    whilefunc();
}
    
whilefunc();
```

Now when I open the page with phone in terminal text "needreload" appears, but

when I open it with PC it says can't set up listener (and that's because I didn't used bind, but if I used bind it would have told can't bind address already in use).

I changed my test.php a lot but still don't know what to do..

So my questions are

1. How to fix this using `socket_bind()` (as after I can't socket_connect, cause no port is being opened)
2. how to fix this (nc port opened method).

I know I wrote my question mixed, but that's because I am also confused.

Comment: Only privileged users are allowed to listen on low-numbered ports. And port 22 may already be in use by the SSH server.

Comment: It's not low-numbered port, it's port 47832.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. 22 isn't the port number, it's the error code.

Comment: You don't use `socket_listen()` on a connected socket. It's used on the server socket that binds to a port, and uses `socket_accept()` to wait for incoming connections.

Comment: Yes but when I socket_bind() it doesn't open up any port

Comment: If you don't specify a port, it binds to a random unused port. You can use `socket_getsockname()` to find out what port it selected. But if you want a client to be able to connect, you should bind to a specific port that it knows to connect to.

Comment: You don't need to use `socket_listen()` when making a connection. That's just used when you want to implement a server in PHP.

Comment: `nc -kl` is already listening on the port, you don't need to listen again in PHP.

Comment: No I binded it to same port - port 47832, after which it tells can't bind address already in use, I opened port 47832 with Netcat, using command nc -kl 47832, now shouldn't socket_bind($socket, "127.0.0.1", 47832) connect to it?

Comment: ok I uderstood nc already listens to it, ok then how is the right way to do this all, I just need to open port without listening?

Comment: Yes, just connect. If you're on the same machine connect to 127.0.0.1, otherwise connect to the public IP.

Comment: can you tell me how open port in non listening mode with nc or other way?

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing here: `socket_connect($socket, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 47832);`. This code runs on the webserver, not the client. So `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is just the name of the current server, not a remote machine to connect to.

Comment: If you don't use the `-l` option, `nc` makes an outgoing connection instead of listening for incoming connections.

Comment: There's no such thing as "open port in non listening mode". Listening on a port is the way you open it.

Comment: No no, I just made a test, and I run both client and server in one .php )) so when I open it with phone it connects to $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], and that's my PC IP "192.168.43.124"

Comment: I think you may be confusing `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: No no, I am ok with that part

Comment: The phone is client, its address is in `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

Comment: HTTP_HOST is my pc, and code checks if client is PC(localhost) it connects to 127.0.0.1 else it connects to  HTTP_HOST,

Comment: Never mind, I get it. When a remote client connects, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is the name/address it connects to instead of `localhost`. But I still don't understand why the PHP script needs to connect to a different server IP depending on where the client is.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is also your PC, so you're connecting to the same host in both cases.

Comment: really? Thank you very much for answers. But how is my PC also 127.0.0.1?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the address that means the current machine. So if you're running the PHP on your PC, 127.0.0.1 is the PC.

Comment: May I also ask, is there way you can open port by PHP script?

Comment: If you want to run a server in a PHP script, you use `socket_bind()` and `socket_listen()`.

Comment: But when I run socket_bind($socket, "127.0.0.1", 47832) and after socket_listen($socket) my browser endless loads, why is that?

Comment: Go to a terminal window and use `nc 127.0.0.1 47832` to connect to it. Then type something so that `socket_read()` will read something.

Comment: So it was working all this time? noo, and yess at the same time, again thanks for helping.

Comment: You wouldn't normally run a server in a script that's run from a web page. You'd do it from a CLI.[

Comment: No it wasn't working because you also called `socket_connect()`. You can't do both listen and connect on the same socket.

Comment: No there was time when I changed it and removed socket_connect()

Comment: Then that probably was working.

Comment: be twice I can't open port in nc without -l option. can you tell me the code?

Comment: See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php#22200 about opening the same port multiple times.

Comment: Yes I already have readen this, and I use this now.

Comment: But wait after socket_bind($socket, "127.0.0.1", 47832), nc 127.0.0.1 47832 tells TCP connection failed

Comment: also I can't open port without -l option in nc

Comment: Is the web page still waiting when you do that?

Comment: You don't want to open the port in nc, you're opening it in PHP. nc is the client, not the server.

Comment: It's really unclear what your real goal is. Why do you want to listen in PHP?

Comment: I tried to connect true nc, I also tried with telnet it couldn;t connect, ok never mind, can I ask for last thing, I'm gonna open port from CLI any sugestions?

Comment: See the example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php

Comment: Well in this test.php I was experimenting and learning after I want to make my chat real-time, even thought I know node is better fore this

Comment: Yeah, this will be complicated in PHP, since you'll have to keep track of multiple connections, and use `socket_select()` to wait for all of them.

Comment: See https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-make-a-live-chat-script-in-php--cms-36513

Answer (score 0):

For me adding this `ob_implicit_flush();` to my code, made my socket accessible from telnet and nc.